# Java Nested Classes Quiz

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

Which of the following statements about static nested classes are true?

1. A static class has no direct access to the elements of an instance its enclosing class.
2. The fields and methods of a static class should contain the modifier static.
3. If the external class Outer contains the static class Nested, then to create an object of the nested class, developer should use new Outer.Nested().
4. A static class should extend its enclosing class.
5. A static class can implement interfaces.
6. A static class can be inherited only from another static class.
7. A static class cannot be inherited from an inner class.
8. A static class can be inherited only from top-level classes.

I am sure about 1 and 3. Would appreciate any help and explanation)

Comment: What does "direct access" mean? (Also see [JEP 181](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181).)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn without creating an object

Comment: Sure, can. `int getX(Outer o) {return o.x;}`. See, no object created.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. A static class has no direct access to the elements of an instance its enclosing class.
```

True. as it is static, it does not have to do anything with an instance.

```
2. The fields and methods of a static class should contain the modifier static.
```

False. A `static class` is just like 'normal' top-level (probably public) classes, so the same rules for its inner workings apply.

```
3. If the external class Outer contains the static class Nested, then to create an object of the nested class, developer should use new Outer.Nested().
```

False. Opinion-based. Not necessary.

```
4. A static class should extend its enclosing class.
```

False. Opinion-based. Not relevant

```
5. A static class can implement interfaces.
```

True. After all, it's just a normal class, just placed somewhere else, inside another class.

```
6. A static class can be inherited only from another static class.
```

False. Behaves just like normal classes, thus can inherit anything that a normal class can.

```
7. A static class cannot be inherited from an inner class.
```

False. Inner classes can inherit static classes.
Example:

```
public class StaticClassStuff {
    class Inner {} // OK
    class Inner2 extends InnerStatic2 {} // OK
    static class InnerStatic extends Inner {} // Compilation ERROR: No enclosing instance of type StaticClassStuff is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation
    static class InnerStatic2 {} // OK
}
```

This is because `Inner` exists only in the **instance** context of `StaticClassStuff`. As such an instance is missing (in the example), `InnerStatic` cannot inherit from anything there.

```
8. A static class can be inherited only from top-level classes.
```

False, see example above.

### Update

Adding to my example above, concerning question (3):

## yes

you eventually have to use the full path name somewhere:

- either in the class name tiself, then you can write `new StaticClassStuff.InnerStatic2()`
- you can also use the sull path: `new stackoverflow.StaticClassStuff.InnerStatic2()`

## no

- you can also use a normal import:

.

```
import stackoverflow.StaticClassStuff.InnerStatic2;

public class StaticClassStuff2 extends InnerStatic2 {}
```

this way you do not need to address the outer class.

- and then, when you're somewhere near the nested class, you also do not have to use the outer class name:

(this is all inside ONE file:)

```
package stackoverflow;

import stackoverflow.StaticClassStuff.InnerStatic2;

public class StaticClassStuff {
    class Inner {} // OK
    class Inner2 extends InnerStatic2 {} // OK
    static class InnerStatic extends Inner {} // Compilation ERROR: No enclosing instance of type StaticClassStuff is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation
    static class InnerStatic2 { // OK
        static class II extends InnerStatic2 {} // OK
        static class IISS extends InnerStatic2 {} // OK
    }

    class Test1 extends InnerStatic2 {} // OK
}

class Test2 extends InnerStatic2 { // OK
    class I2 extends InnerStatic2 {} // OK
    static class SI2 extends InnerStatic2 {} // OK
}
```

So, after all, question (3) is a) opinion-based and b) not necessary in all cases.

Comment: Thank you, sir, however, the third one is true as we need to specify the name of the enclosing class. And in the seventh question, you kind of turn the question upside down. The answer and explanation are correct, so it needs to be true then the quiz is correct. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my answer, so you see why (3) is not really true after all.

Comment: "cannot be inherited from xy" is bad wording, and does not exist in the English language as such. It is either "cannot be inherited by xy" or "cannot inherit xy". This is why I gave the code example, showing both ways.